# ffmpeg how to change audio tbn

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, mp4

I changed my video container with:
`ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i in.mkv -c copy -video_track_timescale 1k out.mp4`
But video_track_timescale only changes video tbn, not audio tbn.

To check it:
`ffprobe -hide_banner .\in.mkv -read_intervals %+0.3 -show_entries frame=media_type,key_frame,pts,pts_time,pkt_duration,pkt_size -print_format compact`

```
frame|media_type=video|key_frame=1|pts=0|pts_time=0.000000|pkt_duration=16|pkt_size=203501|side_data|
side_data|

frame|media_type=audio|key_frame=1|pts=0|pts_time=0.000000|pkt_duration=N/A|pkt_size=622
frame|media_type=video|key_frame=0|pts=17|pts_time=0.017000|pkt_duration=16|pkt_size=5333
frame|media_type=audio|key_frame=1|pts=21|pts_time=0.021000|pkt_duration=21|pkt_size=551
frame|media_type=video|key_frame=0|pts=33|pts_time=0.033000|pkt_duration=16|pkt_size=1221
frame|media_type=audio|key_frame=1|pts=43|pts_time=0.043000|pkt_duration=21|pkt_size=538
frame|media_type=video|key_frame=0|pts=50|pts_time=0.050000|pkt_duration=16|pkt_size=12132
frame|media_type=audio|key_frame=1|pts=64|pts_time=0.064000|pkt_duration=21|pkt_size=662
```

`ffprobe -hide_banner .\out.mp4 -read_intervals %+0.3 -show_entries frame=media_type,key_frame,pts,pts_time,pkt_duration,pkt_size -print_format compact`

```
frame|media_type=video|key_frame=1|pts=0|pts_time=0.000000|pkt_duration=16|pkt_size=203501|side_data|
side_data|

frame|media_type=audio|key_frame=1|pts=0|pts_time=0.000000|pkt_duration=1024|pkt_size=622
frame|media_type=video|key_frame=0|pts=17|pts_time=0.017000|pkt_duration=16|pkt_size=5333
frame|media_type=audio|key_frame=1|pts=1024|pts_time=0.021333|pkt_duration=1024|pkt_size=551
frame|media_type=video|key_frame=0|pts=33|pts_time=0.033000|pkt_duration=16|pkt_size=1221
frame|media_type=audio|key_frame=1|pts=2048|pts_time=0.042667|pkt_duration=1024|pkt_size=538
frame|media_type=video|key_frame=0|pts=50|pts_time=0.050000|pkt_duration=16|pkt_size=12132
frame|media_type=audio|key_frame=1|pts=3072|pts_time=0.064000|pkt_duration=1024|pkt_size=662
```

As we can see, in in.mkv, tbn is same for both audio/video aka 1k. But in out.mp4, tbn is different. Video has 1k tbn because I set it with -video_track_timescale, but where's the similar option for audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such option for audio in MP4. MKV uses a fixed timescale of 1000 which is why audio has that tbn. In MP4, ffmpeg will set it to the sample rate.

The latter is precise.
Notice the timestamps for audio in MKV are not evenly spaced:

```
pts=0|pts_time=0.000000
pts=21|pts_time=0.021000
pts=43|pts_time=0.043000
pts=64|pts_time=0.064000
```

Compare with MP4, which are:

```
pts=0|pts_time=0.000000
pts=1024|pts_time=0.021333
pts=2048|pts_time=0.042667
pts=3072|pts_time=0.064000
```

Comment: Note that even though you said _There's no such option for audio in MP4_, it can be done. It's just that it's not implemented.